# Как добавить сервис-провайдер только для админ-панели?

Tags: php, laravel

Можно ли зарегистрировать сервис-провайдер только если пользователь находится в админ-панели?
Это нужно проверять роутер, к примеру если в админке есть префикс `['prefix' => 'admin']` ?
А вообще нужно что-то наподобии такого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844709/how-do-i-call-a-model-in-a-custom-laravel-5-3-config-file
т.е. чтобы можно было из конфиг-файла обращаться к модели.
В приведённой статье пишут, что нужно создать ключ в файле `app.php` `'user_model' => App\Models\User::class,`
потом обращаться так:  `$user = config('app.user_model'); // app in file name`

но у меня выдаёт ошибку:
`Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:258`

т.е. мне нужно в админке из конфиг файла обращаться к модели.
`config/app.php`
`'page_model' => App\Models\Page::class,`
Использую модуль `adminlte`, и в конфиг-файле `config/adminlte.php` мне нужно узнать количество записей, `'label'       => config('app.page_model')->count(),`
но выдаёт ошибку
т.е. мне нужно сделать так, чтобы это работало только а админке, а если сделать запись в `config/app.php`, тогда лишний запрос будет срабатывать и во фронтенде как я понимаю

**P.S.**

```
use App\Models\Car;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
            abort(403);
        }
        if (auth()->guard('web')->check()) {
            config(['pages' => Car::count()]);
        }else {
            config(['pages' => 22]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**config/adminlte.php**

```
    [
        'text'        => 'pages',
        'url'         => 'admin/pages',
        'icon'        => 'far fa-fw fa-file',
        'label'       => config('pages'),  //количество страниц не работает
        'label_color' => 'success',
    ],
```

т.е. если вместо `config('pages')` поставить любое число, то в меню будет показывать это число, а этот конфиг не работает `config('pages')`
Можете подсказать почему так?
А в контроллерах `config('pages')` эта переменная доступна и выводит количество

**P.S.**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (auth()->guard('web')->check()) {
        config([
            'adminlte.menu' => [
                [
                    'text' => 'cars',
                    'url'  => 'admin/cars',
                    'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-car',
                ],
                [
                    'text'        => 'pages',
                    'url'         => 'admin/pages',
                    'icon'        => 'far fa-fw fa-file',
                    'label'       => Car::whereStatus(1)->count(),
                    'label_color' => 'success',
                ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** **[middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) лучше для этого типа вещей**, так как вы можете применить его к любому маршруту / группе маршрутов, которые вы хотите.

```
class Admin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        //1. Проверка через роль
        // if (!(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role_id ==1))
            // abort(403);
        // 2. 
        if (!Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            abort(403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}

Route::group(['middleware' => ['Admin']], function () {
    Route::get('admin', 'SomeController@action1');
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'SomeController@action2');
    // .....
});
```

**2. Вариант с сервис провайдером**

> Здесь * означает - во всех ваших представлениях доступна переменная $currentUser.

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view)
    {
        if (auth()->guard('admin')->check()) {
            $view->with('currentUser', auth()->user());
        }else {
            $view->with('currentUser', null);
        }
    });
}
```

`view()->composer('*', function($view)` будет выполняться только тогда, когда представление(view) фактически составлено.

**
`$ php artisan config:cache`

[Configuration Caching смотреть здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching)**

Comment: подскажите, а для чего здесь `view()->composer('*', function ($view) ` ? Разве нельзя сразу проверять так: `Auth::check()` ?

Comment: @word `Auth::check()` проверить всех залогиненных пользователей.
Я просто превел пример.Пишите свою логику.
`view()->composer('*', function ($view)` почитайте в документации  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers#the-boot-method

Comment: так а причём здесь `view()->composer('*', function ($view)` ? объясните пожалуйста для чего здесь эта строчка?

Comment: @word https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers#the-boot-method

Comment: @word Это просто пример.Можете удалить ее и оставить свою логику

Comment: @word обновил ответ

Comment: можете подсказать, почему не доступна переменная `config('pages')` в конфиг файле? добавил в вопрос

Comment: может в конфиг-файле переменная `config('pages')` ещё не определена?

Comment: @word  Попробуйте выполнить эти 2 команды
`php artisan config:cache` , 
`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: не, сброс кэша не помогло, получилось сделать переопределив полностью ключ `adminlte.menu`, добавил в вопрос

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, в файле `config/app.php` ведь всё-равно указывается подключение данного провайдера, и получается во фронтенде будет лишняя проверка, и будет запускаться провайдер, который нужен только для админки. Или если делать проверку вашим способом то на проверку много не тратится ресурсов?